# jQuery error (tinyMCE is not defined) on Wordpress admin panel

Tags: jquery, wordpress

After upgrading Wordpress from 3.2 to 3.5 i am getting jQuery error on admin side.
below is the error.

```
Error: ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
Source File: http://domainname.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/wp-langs-en.js?ver=345-20111127
```

Can any one please help me here . Thanks

Comment: it seems some of your plugins installed do not support WordPress 3.5

Comment: [Troubleshooting WP 3.5 - Master List](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list)

Answer (score 27):

It's better to use a declaration:

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

in `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 18):

After reading a million posts about turning everything off, reinstalling everything, waving chicken bones over my keyboard and throwing salt over my shoulder, I decided to get serious.

tinyMCE is not defined means exactly that.  Assumption: it never got loaded.  Check the page source for http://yourdomain.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce.js?ver=359-20131026'> or some other script tag for tiny_mce.js.  I bet you don't have one.  If you do, this is not the solution for you.  If you don't, read on.

I located the code that should be placing the js tag in your page in ...\wp-includes\class-wp-editor.php.

There is an if block "if ( $compressed ) {..." that will load ...\wp-includes\js\tinymce\wp-tinymce.php into the js tag (doesn't work) when $compressed = 1, or ...\wp-includes\js\tinymce\tiny_mce.js when $compressed = 0.  So I set $compressed = 0 just before the if block to force the else.  That fixed my problem.

It's an easy fix and if it doesn't solve your issue it is easily reversed without risking breaking anything else in the WP ecosphere.

Comment: Only solution that works. Gotta love it when we need to edit the core files. Great job Wordpress!

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, disabling the defer javascript enhancements that I made in `functions.php` caused this error to disappear when loading edit pages.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that comes across this and is pulling their hair out a bit, @dale3h's answer was the solution for me.

If you have a function in your `functions.php` which hooks into the `script_loader_tag` filter and doesn't always return the appropriate parts of the original tag markup, or has a bug in it of some kind, it can make some scripts fail to load because scripts to be output to the page are run through this filter first.

Something I've done to avoid this is whitelist script handles depending on what extra attributes I want to give them, so the work can be done conditionally (leaving all other scripts intact):

```
// Manage extra attibutes for enqueued scripts
function foo_script_extras( $tag, $handle, $src ){

    $whitelist = array(
        'js-font-awesome-core'  => array(
            'sri'   => 'sha384-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'defer' => true
        ),
        'js-font-awesome-light' => array(
            'sri'   => 'sha384-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
            'defer' => true
        ),
        'js-popper'             => array(
            'sri'   => 'sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ'
        ),
        'js-bootstrap'          => array(
            'sri'   => 'sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm'
        ),
        'js-gtag'               => array(
            'async' => true
        )
    );

    // Construct the script if we want to give it extra attributes
    if( array_key_exists( $handle, $whitelist ) ){

        // Extra markup
        $extra  = '';
        $mods   = $whitelist[$handle];

        // Check for SRI
        if( array_key_exists( 'sri', $mods ) ){
            $extra .= ' integrity="' . $mods['sri'] . '" crossorigin="anonymous"';
        }

        // Check for deferral
        if( array_key_exists( 'defer', $mods ) ){
            $extra .= ' defer';
        }

        // Check for async
        if( array_key_exists( 'async', $mods ) ){
            $extra .= ' async';
        }

        // Reutrn full script tag
        return '<script src="' . $src . '"' . $extra . '"></script>';

    }else{

        // Return the tag as-is otherwise to avoid breaking it
        return $tag;

    }

}
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'foo_script_extras', 10, 3 );
```

This is not a terribly general solution in terms of checking for which attributes to add to the whitelisted handles, and I would have used something along the lines of "for each attribute of a whitelisted handle, add the key if it's a bool and is true, else add it's value" but SRI needs two attributes (integrity and crossorigin) so I've left it for now.

Additionally, if you don't see `/wp-includes/js/tinymce/` somewhere in your page markup (similar to what @Mar said, but the exact script name can change between versions it seems) then that script ain't loading!